# changing a defineded function name depending on n term used

Tags: function

```
def usersdecision(n):
    if option == n:
       calculation.format(n)()
```

Is there a way to get calculation to become `calculation` + the value of `n` then `()`,
so if `n=1` calculation would become `calculation1()`.

Comment: Add the language tag, Python?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an inelegant way of doing it.  Pass in a list, see how long it is and use the length to call different routines

```
import sys

def userd(*n):
  if (len(n) == 1):
    return calc1(n[0])
  if (len(n) == 2):
    return calc2(n[0],n[1])
  if (len(n) > 2):
    warn("bad input",n)
    sys.exit(1)


def calc1(x):
  return x*2
def calc2(x,x2):
  return x**x2

assert userd(1) == 2
assert userd(2,3) == 8
print "it works"
```